# Firebase Authentication- The onComplete method of onCompleteListener<AuthResult> doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As I mentioned the problem in the title, the app didn't run the `onComplete` method in `onCompleteListener <AuthResult>` when I found this during the debugging mode and this cause the `setUserKey()` method can't be run.

I made this authentication process in a non-activity class which is my model class and I have to call this method when I need it in the SignInActivity class.

Here's my code.

**Model.java** class

```
public String signIn(String emailAddress, String password){
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                setUserKey(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            }
            else
            {
                setUserKey(null);
            }
        }
    });
    return getUserKey();
}
```

So anyone can help me on how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You do know that onComplete is called asynchronously, right? 
the return userkey part is being called before onComplete since its async. 
add some Log.d() calls in onComplete

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Firebase so I have no idea about that. So how I supposed to set the UserKey before it get the UserKey and returned it as null?

Comment: Whats the scenario here? why do you need the Uid for?

Comment: The Uid is going to use in the next activity. BTW I have found out the way to tackle this problem. Thanks for reminding me that onComplete is called asynchronously and this helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: cool, an up vote would be nice :)

Comment: just one click of a mouse, man. you can do it

Comment: Bro, my reputation hasn't reached 15 lol. Sorry for not able to help.  ;C

Comment: @pantos27 upvote from me ;)